# Returning int_ptr from dialogboxes

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

A dialogbox proc has a return type of BOOL but what i'm trying to do

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        {
            HBRUSH g_hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(237, 209, 238));
            HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
            SetBkMode(hdcStatic, TRANSPARENT);
            return (INT_PTR)g_hbrBackground;
        }
```

The above (INT_PTR) cases a performance warning conversion from int_ptr to bool, how it is done?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to return the pointer or whether the pointer is null?

Comment: Hi James, I'm trying to change the background of static controls to be transparent and according to documentation for WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, I must return a handle to the brush.

Comment: Both `LRESULT` and `HBRUSH` are as wide as a pointer, so you should be able to cast the brush. In C++ you should prefer `reinterpret_cast`: `return reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(g_hbrBackground)`.

Comment: "conversion from int_ptr to bool" sounds fishy to me, how is the function which contains that code declared? The correct return type for window procedures is `LRESULT`, not `BOOL`.

Comment: The real problem is that you used a cast in the DialogBox() call.  That shut the compiler up but left you without a paddle.

Comment: Seriously, the number of developers who just cast their way past the compiler telling them about an actual error in their code. Casting the wrong thing to a xxxPROC or a LPCxSTR seem to be the worst culprits.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the declaration of a dialog proc:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(
  __in  HWND hwndDlg,
  __in  UINT uMsg,
  __in  WPARAM wParam,
  __in  LPARAM lParam
);
```

There's no `BOOL` there.

Use correct types and your problem disappears.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Legacy code still has BOOL all around the place. Quite understandable. On Win32 BOOL and INT_PTR are same size anyway, and on Win64 the compiler will bitch on the DialogBox() call.

Answer (score 0):

Typecast a brush handle to BOOL. This is way ugly, but this is how it is.

Answer (score -2):

```
return (BOOL)(g_hbrBackground != 0);
```

should solve the warning.

Comment: Read up on WM_CTLCOLORxxx messages. They actually expect a handle back, not a boolean.

Comment: I doubt that is what the OP wants.

Comment: What the OP means is clear as glass to anyone who ever wrote a WM_CTLCOLOR handler. I did the same many times.